# Why is setting Vue.http for vue-resource ignored?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-resource

I'm using Vue.js 2.3.3, Vue Resource 1.3.3, Vue Router 2.5.3, and I'm trying to set up Vue-Auth. I keep getting a console error, however, that says `auth.js?b7de:487 Error (@websanova/vue-auth): vue-resource.1.x.js : Vue.http must be set.`. I'm setting `Vue.http` in main.js, but vue-resource is not picking it up for some reason.

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Actions from 'actions'
import App from './App'

Vue.use(Actions, {
  locales: ['en', 'zh', 'fr']
})

Vue.http.options.root = 'https://api.example.com'

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  watch: {
    lang: function (val) {
      Vue.config.lang = val
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

actions/index.js

```
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import Router from 'actions/router'
import I18n from 'actions/i18n'

export default {
  install (Vue, options) {
    Vue.use(Router)
    Vue.use(I18n, options.locales)
    Vue.use(require('@websanova/vue-auth'), {
      router: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/router/vue-router.2.x'),
      auth: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/auth/bearer'),
      http: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/http/vue-resource.1.x')
    })
  }
}
```

And if I add `Vue.use(VueResource)` to actions/index.js right below `Vue.use(Router)`, I get a new error: `Error (@websanova/vue-auth): vue-router.2.x.js : Vue.router must be set.`

On the other hand, if I move `Vue.http.options.root = 'https://api.example.com'` to right below the import statements, I get yet another error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined`

Comment: When I `Vue.use(VueResource)`, I get a new error  of `Error (@websanova/vue-auth): vue-router.2.x.js : Vue.router must be set.`

Answer (score 1):

You need to import 'vue-resource' in to your main.js file to get ride of this errors:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
import Actions from 'actions'
import App from './App'

Vue.use(Actions, {
  locales: ['en', 'zh', 'fr']
})

Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.http.options.root = 'https://api.example.com'

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  watch: {
    lang: function (val) {
      Vue.config.lang = val
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Importing 'vue-resource' to the main.js file results in the same error: `Error (@websanova/vue-auth): vue-resource.1.x.js : Vue.http must be set.`

Comment: Any luck fixing this error? A year has passed and no solutions on the internet

Answer (score 0):

Using `axios` and not `vue-resource` this is a working setup for me:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

Vue.router = new VueRouter({
  // Your routes.
})

Vue.use(require('@websanova/vue-auth'), {
    auth: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/auth/bearer.js'),
    http: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/http/axios.1.x.js'),
    router: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/router/vue-router.2.x.js'),
})

App.router = Vue.router

new Vue(App).$mount('#app')
```

> For more guidance you can refer to this great tutorial: https://codeburst.io/api-authentication-in-laravel-vue-spa-using-jwt-auth-d8251b3632e0